# Mathematical model for reaction rate in fixed volume

Tags: kinetics, reaction-control

Is there a way to find the rate of reaction of a chemical reaction inside a closed container that is fixed in volume as a function of time?

Can the answer provide an example reaction (such as baking soda + vinegar $\rightarrow$ carbon dioxide + "the other stuff")?

Comment: Welcome to Chemistry StackExchange. The standard methods are stopped flow, flash photolysis, which is also called 'pump-probe', and temperature and pressure jump methods. These are usually described in physical chemistry textbooks.

Comment: You could also used spectroscopy depending upon whether or not chromophores are available.

Comment: so basically you have to find the function experimentally. I was wondering if you could derive it through mathematical models.

Comment: @user1945827 , the methods I mention normally use spectroscopy to measure changes as time proceeds.